# Multiple wx.Yield() alternative

Tags: python, wxpython

I currently have a wxpython gui application which reads a growing text file and prints this to a wx.TextCtrl window. I need to have two of these running at the same time, but obviously am bumping into the wxYield called recursively error.
Is there an easy alternative to wx.Yield which would allow me to run multiples please?

```
self.running_log = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(5, 5), size=(875,605),
                                       style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)

while True:
    wx.Yield()
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(logPath)
    if fileSize > lastSize:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        newLines = 0
        for line in lines[lastLineIndex:]:
            newLines += 1
            print line.rstrip()
        self.running_log.AppendText(line)
```

Comment: Without knowing more details about the function of your code and how all the bits interact I can only suggest that ```threading``` might be the way to go.  Set up a thread to read from the file and generate an event whenever it does.  Then have that event fire another thread which updates the ```TextCtrl```.

Comment: I don't know what your code is doing, but recursively means that your `wx.Yield()` is allowing some function to run, that is also long-running and therefore calls `wx.Yield()`. You should make sure that when you call the yield, that all it can do is GUI updates and the user can't cause something else long-running to happen.

Comment: have amended the question slightly so that you can see that it is in a never ending while True loop. This is the small section I need to thread, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the wxPython wiki: [LongRunningTasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks).
There you'll see two alternatives to using wxYield: threading or putting your processing into the EVT_IDLE handler.

But since you're already using wxYield, let me suggest a solution you can try before changing to something else: Use a flag to indicate whether you are already running or not. If the flag is true, don't let the code execute wxYield again.

When you call `wx.Yield()`, wxPython will take control and process any events it needs to take care of. When that is finished, your long running task will proceed again, right after your yield call. So you can put all your processing in a loop and let it spin there as long as it needs to. By adding a flag you limit the entry point to only be where the yield is. When your processing has finished you release your 'lock' by toggling your flag, and the entry point of your code changes to be the actual method invocation again.

Something along the lines of:

```
if not running:
    running = True
    while True:
        wx.Yield()
        fileSize = os.path.getsize(self.logPath)
        if fileSize > lastSize:
            lines = infile.readlines()
            newLines = 0
            for line in lines[lastLineIndex:]:
                newLines += 1
                self.running_log.AppendText(line)
        # When you are finished, set running to False and break
```

Note that it might be a good idea to check how often `getsize` is called. If it happens too often you could limit it by ensuring that some short amount of time has elapsed, to avoid excessive calls slowing down your system.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is currently how it is working, sort of, but I want to add another identical task, so will have to look at threading.

Comment: If you encapsulate this behavior into a class, you could just make two instances of the class and you can run your two tasks. Each instance would have their own data, such as `self.running`, to distinguish them.

Comment: But threads are fine, just make sure you don't update the GUI from any of your threads but send events to the GUI thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't the wx.SafeYield() designed to solve this exact problem?

E.g., see here [enter link description here](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-Yield-wx-SafeYield-wx-App-Yield-td2371477.html)